# Product topology on $X = \{f \ | \ f: \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow \{0,1\}\}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let
$$
X = \{f \ | \ f: \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow \{0,1\}\}.
$$
Define a map $d: X \times X \longrightarrow [0, \infty)$ as
$$
d(f,g) = \inf \left\{\frac{1}{k+1} \ : \ f(i)=g(i), \quad \forall i<k \right\}.
$$
We know that $d$ is a metric on X.

For a given $\varepsilon >0$, we define
$$
S_{\varepsilon}(f) = \{g \in X \ : \ d(f,g) < \varepsilon\} 
$$
as $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $f$ for each $f \in X$. Then,
$$
\mathcal{B} = \{S_{\varepsilon}(f) \ : \ f \in X, \quad \varepsilon > 0\}
$$
forms a base for a topology $\tau_1$ on $X$.

On the other hand, we can consider $X$ as
$$
X = \prod_{i \in \mathbb{N}} X_i,
$$
where $X_i = \{0, 1\}$.

Let $\nu_i$ denote the discrete topology on $X_i$ for each $i \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, we define a product topology $\tau_2$ on X as
$$
\mathcal{O} \in \tau_2 \implies \mathcal{O} = \prod_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \mathcal{O}_i,
$$
where $\mathcal{O}_i \in \nu_i$ for any $i \in \mathbb{N}$.

**My Claim** is to show that $\tau_1 = \tau_2$.

Is it clear? If so, how can we write a formal proof? Do you have any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's not clear until it's clear, and then it's clear. Speaking from my own personal experience. :-)

Comment: $\tau_2$ is not the product topology on $\prod_i X_i$. The claim is true for the product topology, but not for $\tau_2$.

Comment: $\tau_2$ as you defined it is the discrete topology on $X$.

Comment: Your $\tau_2$ is what is known as the [box topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_topology).  As others said, it is in general different from the box topology, and it is discrete when all the $X_i$ are discrete.

Comment: How can I define the product topology $\tau_2$ over X so that $\tau_1 = \tau_2$. In fact, my aim is to prove that $\tau_1$ is a product topology on $X$.

Comment: It's the weakest topology making all projections continuous. Look up product or tychonoff topology for more details.

Comment: @tomasz Can you explain  what the elements of the product topology are for this example?

Comment: @bozcan: Arbitrary unions of basic open sets, i.e. sets of the form $\prod_{i\in \mathbf N} U_i$, where all but finitely many $U_i$ are equal to $X_i$, and all are open in $X_i$.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that $\tau_1\neq \tau_2$, because we can verify that $\tau_2$ is the discrete topology over $X$. In order to prove this, let $x\in X$ be an element of the space product, existing $x_i \in X_i = \{0,1\}$ for every $i\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x = (x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)$. Once $X_i$ is equipped with the discrete topology, $\{x_i\}$ is open in $X_i$ for every $i$. Thus, $\{x\} = \displaystyle \prod_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\{x_i\}$ is open in $(X,\tau_2)$, showing that $\tau_2$ is the discrete topology over $X$.

On the other hand, given $x = (x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots) \in X$ and any $\varepsilon > 0$, fix $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n+1}< \varepsilon$. So, $y = (x_0,x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n,x_{n+1},0,0,0,0,\dots)$ and $z = (x_0,x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n,x_{n+1},1,1,1,1,\dots)$ are both elements of $S_{\varepsilon}(x)$. Therefore, no basic open set of $\tau_1$ is singleton, concluding that $\tau_1$ is not the discrete topology over $X$. Thus, $\tau_1\neq \tau_2$.

However, the distance $d$ that you defined generates the topology $\tau$ over $X$ similar to $\tau_2$ but whose basic open sets have the form $$\prod_{i\in\mathbb{N}}Y_i,$$ where $Y_i$ is an open set of $X_i$ (with the discrete topology) for $i\in F$ and $Y_i = X_i = \{0,1\}$ otherwise, where $F\subset\mathbb{N}$ is a finite set.

Comment: You're right, but I think you should mention in your answer that $\tau_2$ is not the product topology (which you describe at the end), but rather, the box topology.

Comment: @tomasz How can I define the product topology $\tau_2$ over X so that $\tau_1 = \tau_2$. In fact, my aim is to prove that $\tau_1$ is a product topology on $X$.

Answer (score 0):

$\tau_2$, as you defined it, is discrete,  and is in fact the box topology,  not the product topology.

The product topology is not discrete,  by Tychonoff's theorem,  since we know no infinite discrete set is compact.

As to whether  $\tau_1$ is the same as the product topology,  that remains to be seen.